# install spring-security-core plugin into plugin, which then is installed in application

Tags: grails, spring-security

I've just switched to grails 2.2 and have got a major plugin problem. I've got an application - my-app and a plugin - my-plugin. I want to install spring-security-core plugin into my-plugin, and then install my-plugin into my-app. When I've done this and did s2-quickstart, so that LoginController got created. I can start my-plugin with no problems now, but when I try to start my-app it complains that it cannot find any springsecurity classes. Errors looks like this:

12: unable to resolve class org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes @ line 12, column 1.
7: unable to resolve class org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountExpiredException @ line 7, column 1.
11: unable to resolve class org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder @ line 11, column 1.

It looks to me, like only my-plugin can see spring security plugin dependencies, and my-app cannot, so they didn't cascade even thought according to manual they should have.

I've also tryed to install spring-security-core plugin by adding in BuildConfig.conf this: 
compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3" 
but it didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `install-plugin` in a plugin, it's only installed locally by adding a line in `application.properties`. It doesn't get exported as a dependency of your plugin. This could be used for plugins like `code-coverage` where you want to use it during development and testing but not force users to also install it.

In older versions of Grails the `dependsOn` map in the plugin descriptor was used to express plugin dependencies. This is now deprecated in favor of dependencies registered in the `plugins` secton of `BuildConfig.groovy`. This is both for consistency and to take advantage of the more fine-grained features supported by the dependency DSL including specifying scopes and exclusions. This is also true for applications - don't use `install-plugin` for either apps or plugins, always use `BuildConfig.groovy`.

Take a look at the [spring-security-ldap plugin's BuildConfig.groovy](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ldap/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy). It has a compile-scope dependency on the core plugin, plus one for the `hibernate` plugin that's not exported (since it's just for testing) and a build-scope dependency on the release plugin (also not exported since it's just used to release the plugins).

You should probably using a similar dependency on the core plugin in your `BuildConfig.groovy`. Delete any plugin references in your `application.properties` and convert to `BuildConfig.groovy` syntax and run `grails clean` followed by `grails compile`.

Comment: I've created one new app and one plugin-sstest. In plugin I added " compile ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.3' " in plugins section. Didn't touch dependencies section, becouse I don't really get what's going on there. In main app I imported my plugin adding this to BuildConfig.conf: "grails.plugin.location.'plugin-sstest' = "../plugin-sstest". I can compile this, and everything works fine untill I use s2-quickstart on my plugin-sstest. Then it stops to compile and starts to throw errors, that it can't find dependencies from spring security plugin. So the plugin is still not pulled into main app

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Burt for your advice. I've used it and here's what I came to:

I created a plugin-app and installed spring-security-core plugin in it (using DataSource.groovy, and not install plugin). Then I created a main-app and installed my plugin-app (again using DataSource.groovy). When I did this in grails 2.1.1 everything worked just fine - I could use spring-security in my main-app, so the dependency got pulled just right. When I did everything the same, but in grails 2.2 I couldn't use spring-security in my main-app, so dependencies didn't get pulled. That's why I think this might be some kind of a bug in new grails version.

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer - it should be a comment on your question or an answer.

Comment: Thx for advice - I'll do it your way next time.

Anyway I found a workaround for this problem. Instead of depending on grails to pull nesesery dependencies I pull them myself. For instance if I install spring-security-core in my plugin-app, and install plugin-app into main-app I also install spring-security-core in main app. It's annoying, but it works.